# Chrome float: right image not aligning

Tags: google-chrome, button, alignment

I have this search button that is really giving me a hard time. I am trying to get it to line up properly with the search input area and when I finally got it to work in Firefox, it decided to get all weird in Chrome. Its like something is pushing the button down when viewed in Chrome.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="searchCon">    
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="http://somesite.com/">
<div>
<label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search Our Site:</label>
<input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s">
<input type="image" value="Search" src="button.png" id="searchsubmit" style="opacity: 1; float: right;">
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
    #searchCon {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  height:37px;
  padding: 0px 10px 10px 280px;
  color:#2a2a2a;
```

}

I have been reading tons of forums, articles, etc and cannot get this little button to work properly in Chrome.

Please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div id="searchCon">    
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="http://somesite.com/">
<div style="float:left">
<label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search Our Site:</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
</div>
<div style="float:right;padding-top:2px">
    <input type="image" value="Search" src="button.png" id="searchsubmit" style="opacity: 1; " />
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#searchCon {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  height:37px;
  padding: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
  color:#2a2a2a;
}
```

Comment: Aziz, unfortunately all this did was push down the search bar in Chrome as well as in Firefox.

Comment: Ok but do you get the image and search input area line up properly now, or is the image still pushed below the search area?

Comment: In both Chrome and Firefox the button is pushed a few pixels above the search bar.

Comment: I tried changing the padding to padding: 10px 10px 10px 0px; but this didn't do anything.

Comment: Tried another approach, lets see if it helps you. Check this link: http://jsfiddle.net/B5wcf/

Comment: This helped in that I can apply a top padding for just the button, but it pushed the search bar up about 10 px and I can't get it to come back down.

Comment: Use `padding` (make top padding to 10px) in `#searchCon` css